# Another Group by Order By MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, filesort

I know this has been beaten to a pulp - but I've havent seen a really good answer that works. Here is my situation: I have the following query:

```
SELECT items.item_name, sort_order as total_count, user_top_favorites.item_id.item_id
        FROM user_top_favorites
        INNER JOIN items ON user_top_favorites.item_id = items.item_id
        WHERE user_top_favorites.user_id = 1
        GROUP by user_top_favorites.item_id.item_id
        ORDER BY sort_order asc
        LIMIT 0 , 6
```

I've tried the following indices:

```
user_sort (user_id, item_id, sort_order)
user_sort (item_id, user_id, sort_order)
user_sort (user_id, sort_order, item_id)
```

And I always get: `Using temporary; Using filesort`

What is the correct index here to avoid temporary and filesort?

**UPDATE:**
`user_sort` is just the name of the index I created, and the the index belongs in the the `user_top_favorites` table.

Comment: How many rows does the query generate before limit and group by?

Comment: Why do you use group, if you don't have any aggregated functions?

Comment: Why would an index on `user_sort` have an effect on a query that doesn't use that table?

Comment: @GordonLinoff that's just the name of the index for my standards.

Comment: What table is the index on?  You should edit the question to correct the index and to address the other comments.

Comment: @Joni There are 6 - only 6.

Comment: @GordonLinoff user_top_favorites

Comment: @Uriil there is a situation, where there may be duplicate entries in this top_favorites - so the group is to filter out those.

Comment: @gregavola In this case result will be unpredictable and might change over time. You might have different item_name and total_count for same item id

Comment: That's an inappropriate use of GROUP BY. If you don't care which results are returned, then there's something wrong with your data model.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can eliminate the `group by`, if you don't have duplicates in `user_top_favorites` (on `user_id, sort_order` and `items` (on `item_id`).  You can also do the selection of the top 6 before the `join`.  Although this materializes a table, it is so small that there is no performance hit.

```
    SELECT i.item_name, utf.sort_order as total_count, utf.item_id.item_id
    FROM (select utf.*
          from user_top_favorites utf
          where utf.user_id = 1
          order by utf.sort_order
          limit 6
         ) utf join
         items i
         ON utf.item_id = i.item_id
    ORDER BY utf.sort_order asc;
```

If this query is what you need, then the following indexes should help performance:  `user_top_favorites(user_id, sort_order)` and `items(item_id)`.

If you want to be a little risky, you can eliminate the outside `order by`.  MySQL does not guarantee the ordering of subqueries, but I think you will get them in the order you want in practice.  However, sorting 6 records should really take a trivial amount of time.